# Working with javascript variable arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to return the results from each list, using an array of variables containing the names of the lists.

```
var filters = ["colour", "size", "len", "s_length", "occasion"];
var colour = ["black", "white", "blue", "brown", "gold",
              "green", "grey", "multi", "nude", "orange", "pink",
              "purple", "red", "silver", "yellow"];
var size = ["XS", "S", "M", "L", "UK 6", "UK 8",
            "UK 10", "UK 12", "UK 14", "UK 16", "UK 18+"];
var len = ["maxi", "midi", "mini"];
var s_length = ["sleeveless", "short", "3/4", "long"];
var occasion = ["casual", "party/evening", "work"];

for (var h = filters.length; h--;) {
  console.log(filters[h])
  for (var i = filters[h].length; i--;) {
    console.log(filters[h[i]])
  }
}
```

I'm used to python, and this seems like it would work as I want, but instead of returning the array items I get an undefined result for filters[h[i]]

What am I doing wrong here? TIA

Comment: That is because h is an integer and doing h[i] will return undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot get a reference to a local variable from a string in JavaScript. There is no way to get to the array in `colour` if all you have is the string `"colour"`.

What you can do is have your filters all in an object ("dictionary" for Python people):

```
var filters = {
  colour: [
    "black", "white", "blue", "brown", "gold",
    "green", "grey", "multi", "nude", "orange", "pink",
    "purple", "red", "silver", "yellow"
  ],
  size: [
    "XS", "S", "M", "L", "UK 6", "UK 8",
    "UK 10", "UK 12", "UK 14", "UK 16", "UK 18+"
  ],
  len: [
    "maxi", "midi", "mini"
  ],
  s_length: [
    "sleeveless", "short", "3/4", "long"
  ],
  occasion: [
    "casual", "party/evening", "work"
  ]
};
```

then iterate on that to pick up the various values.

```
Object.keys(filters).forEach(function(filterName) {
  filters[filterName].forEach(function(option) {
    console.log(option);
  });
});
```

Comment: @NeilVillareal: I think you replied to a wrong person...? I never mentioned `h[i]`...

Answer (score 1):

`filters` is an array of strings. When you are doing:

```
 filters[h[i]]
```

You are trying to access the property `i` of the element `h` of the array `filters`. As `filters` is an array of strings, `h` will point to a string, and `i` will try to dig into that string. And it will fail to do so (won't find a thing).

Probably you should declare all the other arrays:

```
 var colour = ...
 var size = ...
 var len = ...
```

And last do this:

```
var filters = [colour, size, len, s_length, occasion];
```

So now `filters` is an array of arrays, and you can dig into a element of each of those arrays

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the same logic correctly in JavaScript you can do it like this

```
var filters = ["colour", "size", "len", "s_length", "occasion"];
var variables = {
  colour : ["black", "white", "blue", "brown", "gold",
              "green", "grey", "multi", "nude", "orange", "pink",
              "purple", "red", "silver", "yellow"],
  size : ["XS", "S", "M", "L", "UK 6", "UK 8",
            "UK 10", "UK 12", "UK 14", "UK 16", "UK 18+"],
  len : ["maxi", "midi", "mini"],
  s_length : ["sleeveless", "short", "3/4", "long"],
  occasion : ["casual", "party/evening", "work"],
};

for (var h = filters.length; h--;) {
  console.log(filters[h])
  for (var i = variables[filters[h]].length; i--;) {
    console.log(variables[filters[h]][i])
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try this. You can test it here https://jsfiddle.net/Lk9xcex2/.

```
var filters = ["colour", "size", "len", "s_length", "occasion"];
var colour = ["black", "white", "blue", "brown", "gold",
              "green", "grey", "multi", "nude", "orange", "pink",
              "purple", "red", "silver", "yellow"];
var size = ["XS", "S", "M", "L", "UK 6", "UK 8",
            "UK 10", "UK 12", "UK 14", "UK 16", "UK 18+"];
var len = ["maxi", "midi", "mini"];
var s_length = ["sleeveless", "short", "3/4", "long"];
var occasion = ["casual", "party/evening", "work"];

for (var h = filters.length; h--;) {
    console.log(eval(filters[h]));
}
```